# Input a dynamic value into @FetchRequest, to fetch a single entity from core data in SwiftUI

Tags: core-data, swiftui, ios13, xcode11

I saw same type of error but with different kind of code here, so I think it's better to ask a new question on this context. I have attempted to "find a specific entity" from core data by trying to pass a string variable (which use as a key to find that entity) called `title` into `@FetchRequest`. This is part of the code I have used

```
struct AccountMainPage: View {
    //*** User input ***
    var title: String

    //*** Core data enviroment initialisation ***
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    @FetchRequest(fetchRequest: Accounts.getSpecificAccounts(findTitle: title)) var fetchedAccount: FetchedResults<Accounts>


    var body: some View {
    //SOME CODE HERE
    }
}
```

The public class `Accounts` has the extension:

```
extension Accounts {
    static func getSpecificAccounts(findTitle: String) -> NSFetchRequest<Accounts> {
    let request: NSFetchRequest<Accounts> = Accounts.fetchRequest() as! NSFetchRequest<Accounts>

    let findDescriptor = NSPredicate(format: "title == %@",findTitle)

    request.predicate = findDescriptor

    return request
    }
}
```

However, the line with `@FetchRequest(fetchRequest: Accounts.getSpecificAccounts(findTitle: title)) var fetchedAccount: FetchedResults<Accounts>` has a syntax error:

> Cannot use instance member 'title' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: you are initializing the title you can just give it value empty string

Comment: @fakiho I don't understand what you're trying to say? I want to input a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@FetchRequest` is dynamic property which is initialised, as any other property, before your `AccountMainPage` `init` is called, so `self` is not available yet, that is why you cannot use `title` property which is a member of `self`, and that is about what compiler error tells.

So here is a possible solution: we initialise fetch request property with stub request and then in `init`, which is called later, reinitialise it with real fetch request.

Here is an approach demo (all unrelated things cut):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var title: String

    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    @FetchRequest(fetchRequest: Accounts.fetchRequest()) var fetchedAccount: FetchedResults<Accounts>

    init(title: String) {
        self.title = title
        _fetchedAccount = FetchRequest<Accounts>(fetchRequest: Accounts.getSpecificAccounts(findTitle: title))
    }

...
```

Comment: Thanks it works partially, what is the difference between `fetchedAccount` and `_fetchedAccount` and which one would I use in the `var body: some View {...}` section to call the entity inside?

Comment: `_fetchedAccount` is a request, `fetchedAccount` is a response, so if you are about showing results, then you should use `fetchedAccount`.

Comment: @Asperi is it possible to fetch just a single object from Core Data, For example: I don't have multiple objects of user profile, there is only single user profile and I would like to just get a single object, but I couldn't. I want to get user profile as a single object instead of array like [UserProfile]. I want to do something like this :
@FetchRequest(entity: UserProfile.entity()) var userProfile: FetchedResult<UserProfile>.... I don't know if that is possible

Comment: Is this still the preferred method of customizing a FetchRequest's predicate based on a parameter passed to a view? I've been trying to use the new iOS 13 nsPredicate Dynamic Property in .onAppear() and find that the @FetchRequest's predicate gets set to nil after the first time SwiftUI updates the first View update. Anyone else seen this? –

Comment: Try this approach, you don't need to implement the init() thing. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68530633/how-to-use-a-fetchrequest-with-the-new-searchable-modifier-in-swiftui