# How to filter by ALL if input is empty? SwiftUI/Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, swiftui

Below in my code I have simple setup whereby my FetchRequest is filtered by a string, this string comes from a text field that the user can input into. How do I return all results if said text field is empty?

```
struct TechList: View {

var fetchRequest: FetchRequest<HearingDevice>
@State private var selectedDevice: String?
@ObservedObject var model = Model()
init(filter: String) {
    fetchRequest = FetchRequest<HearingDevice>(entity: HearingDevice.entity(), sortDescriptors: [], predicate: NSPredicate(format: "model CONTAINS %@", filter))

}

var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .center){
        List(fetchRequest.wrappedValue, id: \.self) { device in
            VStack(alignment: .center) {
                HStack{
                    Text(device.model ?? "Unknown" + " ")
                        .font(.system(size: 17))
                        .fontWeight(.medium)
                     .foregroundColor(self.selectedDevice == device.model ? Color.white:Color.init(hex: "47535B"))
                         .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                        .padding(.leading)
                 Spacer()
             }
            }
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: 60)
            .background(self.selectedDevice == device.model ? Color.init(hex: "666699"):Color.init(hex: "F6F6F6"))
            .cornerRadius(7.0)
            .onTapGesture {
            self.model.deviceModel = device.model!
             withAnimation(.spring()){
                 self.selectedDevice = device.model!
             }
          }
        }
        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .padding(.top, 160.0)
        .padding(.bottom, 20.0)
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way I can return ALL of my results if there is no filter provided?

Update based on Asperi's comment:

```
struct TechList: View {
var filter: String
@FetchRequest(fetchRequest: HearingDevice.fetchRequest()) var fetchRequest: FetchedResults<HearingDevice>
@State private var selectedDevice: String?
@ObservedObject var model = Model()
init(filter: String) {
    self.filter = filter
    _fetchRequest = FetchRequest<HearingDevice>(entity: HearingDevice.entity(), sortDescriptors: [], predicate: NSPredicate(format: "model CONTAINS %@", filter))

}

var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .center){
        List(fetchRequest, id: \.self) { device in
            VStack(alignment: .center) {
                HStack{
                    Text(device.model ?? "Unknown" + " ")
                        .font(.system(size: 17))
                        .fontWeight(.medium)
                     .foregroundColor(self.selectedDevice == device.model ? Color.white:Color.init(hex: "47535B"))
                         .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                        .padding(.leading)
                 Spacer()
             }
            }
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: 60)
            .background(self.selectedDevice == device.model ? Color.init(hex: "666699"):Color.init(hex: "F6F6F6"))
            .cornerRadius(7.0)
            .onTapGesture {
            self.model.deviceModel = device.model!
             withAnimation(.spring()){
                 self.selectedDevice = device.model!
             }
          }
        }
        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .padding(.top, 160.0)
        .padding(.bottom, 20.0)
     }
   }
 }
```

I have implemented the approach from your first comment although there are no errors and the code executes fine, my list remains empty. How do I pull the fetch request into my list if I am not using .wrappedValue?

Comment: You might find [Input a dynamic value into @FetchRequest, to fetch a single entity from core data in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59158694/input-a-dynamic-value-into-fetchrequest-to-fetch-a-single-entity-from-core-dat/59169794?r=SearchResults&s=1|52.9460#59169794) topic helpful

Comment: or [Is there a way to modify fetched results with a predicate after they are initialized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59344515/is-there-a-way-to-modify-fetched-results-with-a-predicate-after-they-are-initial/59345830?r=SearchResults&s=3|45.2981#59345830)

Comment: @Asperi Updated my question to reflect your answer :)

Comment: I think the second post if more close to your case, because if there is not filter you should not specify predicate at all. So better design would be `MainView + filterString` & `ResultView` with a reconstructed fetch request in `init` (as you currently do) depending on filterString content with or w/o predicate.

Comment: Hi so I got it all working but now I am faced with optimisation issues, is this something that is common when loading medium sized data sets? Filtering takes 2-3 seconds an my list of data is literally 70 items. Perhaps its my search field implementation. I am using onEditingChanged to check for changes in the predicate but filtering takes a long time.